# Javascript onclick function on div works only in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this code to call a function on a div when it's clicked:

```
<div class="buttonsim" runat="server">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.buttonsim").click(function() {
      window.location.href("sim.aspx");
    });
  });
```

It works on IE but not on Chrome and Firefox> Am I doing something wrong? Is it missing something?

Comment: I wonder how on earth its working on IE

Comment: `<div class="buttonsim" runat="server" >` ??? This is what an `<asp:Panel>` is for.

Comment: it will not work in any browser

Comment: Consider including the actual issue in the title, `window.location.href not working in chrome/firefox`. Your current title suggests the event handler isn't working, which it is, just not your function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`window.location.href` is not a method, it should be

```
window.location.href = "sim.aspx";
```

If you really want to use a method, you can use [`assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location#assign)

```
window.location.assign("sim.aspx");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually set the `window.location.href` property as you are currently using it as a method :

```
    $("div.buttonsim").click(function() {
        window.location.href = "sim.aspx";
    });
```